# Why is my function not updating the data every second?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, compiler-errors, updates

I have a simple component to display cryptocurrencies and I want to update the amount every second (and reflect the updated value). I can display the amount but my function to add 1 every second is not working. I tested with something else like `alert()` and that was working. Is it my selector?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul class="crypto-list">
      <li v-for="(currency, idx) in currencies" :key="idx" class="currency">
        <span class="currency__acronym">{{ currency.acronym}} </span>
        <h2 class="currency__name">{{ currency.name }}</h2>
        <span class="currency__amount"> {{ currency.amount }} </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Cryptocurrency',
    data() {
      return {
        currencies: [{
          name: 'Ethereum',
          acronym: 'ETH',
          amount: 1,
        },{
          name: 'ICON',
          acronym: 'ICX',
          amount: 40,
        },{
          name: 'Nano',
          acronym: 'XRB',
          amount: 14,
        }],        
      };
    },

    mounted () {
      this.addNumber();
    },

    methods: {
      addNumber: function() {
        setInterval(function() { 
          this.currencies[0].amount += 1;
          this.currencies[1].amount += 1;
          this.currencies[2].amount += 1;
        }, 1000);
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Your not getting errors in console?  I would expect `this` to be out of scope here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the function passed into the `setInterval` function has a different context. We can use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to explicitly assign the context of the function passed into the `setInterval`.

```
addNumber: function() {
    setInterval(function(){ 
      ++this.currencies[0].amount;
      ++this.currencies[1].amount;
      ++this.currencies[2].amount;
    }.bind(this), 1000);
},
```

---

**Edit:**

For ES6 and above, you can use the [arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
addNumber() {
    setInterval(() => { 
      ++this.currencies[0].amount;
      ++this.currencies[1].amount;
      ++this.currencies[2].amount;
    }, 1000);
},
```

Comment: Not a vue user, so might be wrong,. But to keep `this` context, don't you also want ->  `addNumber: () => {`

Comment: @Keith, that is already handled by Vue as vue automatically binds the context into the component's methods. The cause of the out of context in here is the function passed into the `setInterval()`, so converting it into an arrow function will fix it.

Comment: Thank you! I will mark as solved when I can

Comment: Ok, did wonder if Vue handled this for you.

Comment: @TkyStm I've updated my answer, my previous answer was using ES6 arrow function syntax. I've updated it to include non-ES6 version as not all browsers currently support the arrow function syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Its the use of `setInterval`, this is run every `x` second, in your case 1 sec because you passed `1000` as a parameter for the interval.

cf. [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)